# How can I make this backlink checker regex better, its missing some sites

Tags: php, mysql, regex

```
<? $mysite = ('websiteurl');?>
<? echo $mysite; ?> Links not found
<?
  $time_limit = 3600;
  set_time_limit($time_limit);
  include_once("myconnect.php");
  $sql0="select * from trade where 1  ";
  $sql0=$sql0." order by a1 asc";
  $query=mysql_query($sql0);
  $cnt=1;
  while ( ($rs_query=mysql_fetch_array($query)) )
  { 
    if($cnt%2<>0)  
     $bgcolor="#EEEEEE";
    else  
     $bgcolor="#FFFFFF"; 
    $ok="";
    $page="";
    $page = @implode ('', @file ($rs_query["a2"]));
    if ($page)
    {
      if ( ereg("< *[a|A] +.*[h|H][r|R][e|E][f|F] *=.*(http://)?(www.)?(".$mysite.").*", $page) )
      {
        $ok="yes";
      }
      else
      {
        $ok="no";
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $ok="no";
    }
    if($ok=="no"){ echo $rs_query["a1"];}
  } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem might come from the "greedy matches" such as `.*` in your regex -- they will keep matching as much as they can, gobbling two tags where you thought only one was getting matched. Not sure if you can fix that in `ereg`, but then, aren't you supposed to use the more advanced `preg` since many years ago?  With `preg` you can ask explicitly for a "lazy" (aka "non-greedy") match by using `.*?`, which might fix this issue (there may be others -- if you give us examples of problems you observe, it will be easier to help you debug!-).

Comment: Thanks, ill see what I can do, this is an old script ive had for a while.